# php automatically adds slashes to quotes

Tags: php, xml

All I'm trying to do is to get xml file content, show is in the textarea and update the file content if the for is submited. I use this code:

```
$fname = "../data.xml";

if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
 $content = $_POST["update"];
 $fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
 fwrite($fhandle,$content);
}

$fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
$content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));

fclose($fhandle);
```

The content is updated when I press submit but it adds slashes to quotes. For example this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

becomes:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
```

and if I re-submit:

```
<?xml version=\\"1.0\\" encoding=\\"utf-8\\"?>
```

Can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an issue with Magic Quotes, we ran into it as well. Use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the POST input before doing anything with it.

Comment: This is nothing to do with "UNIX" and everything to do with magic quotes being enabled on the server.

Comment: Daaaaang. I hate Magic Quotes now, I've spent quite a few hours trying to see what my issue was. I thought it was the encoding..

Comment: This is not the case for me. All is off but still happening. :/

Answer (score 11):

This is probably due to [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/security.magicquotes). Try to [disable or remove them](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling).

Answer (score 2):

Disable `magic_quotes_gpc` from `php.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

Magic Quotes should always be disabled; it's a security risk.
If you can't edit the config, or if you putting the code on multiple servers with different settings that can't be changed, you need the code to check for it. This example was found here --> http://php.robm.me.uk/#toc-MagicQuotes

```
function remove_magic_quotes($array) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $array[$k] = remove_magic_quotes($v);
        } else {
            $array[$k] = stripslashes($v);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_GET    = remove_magic_quotes($_GET);
    $_POST   = remove_magic_quotes($_POST);
    $_COOKIE = remove_magic_quotes($_COOKIE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable magic quotes by adding this line to your .htaccess file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [stripslashes()](http://dk.php.net/stripslashes)