# Yii2: How to stop yii2 from escaping $_POST variables?

Tags: php, yii2, escaping

Yii2 escapes all `$_POST` variables by adding additional slashes. How to stop that?
(`Magic quotes` are disabled in PHP. Additional slashes are added by `yii2`, not by `PHP`)

Comment: What you are entering and what value you are getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. Yii doesn't change $_POST. And magic quotes are disabled.

The reason $_POST variables are escaped is because in my yii app I'm loading Wordpress wp-load.php and **it is Wordpress who changed $_POST**.

It is done in wp-settings.php by calling wp_magic_quotes() function. To avoid this I remember contents of $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_COOKIE and $_SERVER, then load wp-load.php, cache all data I need from WP and revert back.

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 doesn't change `$_POST` in any way because it's considered a bad practice.
The problem is most likely with magic quotes, check it once again more accurately.

Related questions:

- [Why are $_POST variables getting escaped in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496455/why-are-post-variables-getting-escaped-in-php)
- [php automatically adds slashes to quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715721/php-automatically-adds-slashes-to-quotes)